# Conditional Bar Chart with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 visualization with a map and a bar chart. I am trying to get the bar chart to change depending on which circle on the map is clicked. Not sure how to do this. I have a function in my bar_chart.js file named update(newData) and a few extra arrays for the different circles on the map. [Here](https://bl.ocks.org/centem/8e2ea8aa5ad9a283a7d368a87bb3ab99) is the link to the bl.ocks for the map and bar char.

js code for map

```
var myData = [21, 3, 5, 21, 15];
//Width and height
var w = 200;
var h = 125;
var yScale = null;

function draw(initialData) {
  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(initialData.length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

  yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(initialData)])
    .range([0, h]);

  //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(initialData)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");

  svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(initialData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - yScale(d) + 14;
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "white");
}

draw(myData);

//update function
function update(newData) {
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(newData)]);

  var rects = d3.select("#chart svg")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(newData);

  // enter selection
  rects
    .enter().append("rect");

  // update selection
  rects
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d);
    })

  // exit selection
  rects
    .exit().remove();

  var texts = d3.select("#chart svg")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(newData);

  // enter selection
  texts
    .enter().append("rect");

  // update selection
  texts
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - yScale(d) + 14;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    })

  // exit selection
  texts
    .exit().remove();
}

var mk = [10,17,20,14,8];
var cn = [18,4,9,20,15];
var nd = [5,12,7,15,21];

d3.select("#update").on("click", function() { update(newData); });
```

Comment: In your on-click handler where is `newData` defined? I can't find it anywhere in the code and the numbers after the update resemble the `nd` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to incorporate the barchart data in your `cities.csv` file.

In the on-click handler of `cities.csv` where you show the tooltip you have to transform the data from the CSV into an array and call the bar chart `update()` method with this array.

One way of doing is to replace the `,` from the bar chart data with another char and split the string and convert the parts to numbers.

```
var cityData = d.barchart.split('#').map(Number);
update(cityData);
```

You also have to set the attributes of the new `rect`s and `text`s of the bar chart. And the x-position will change if the number of bars change.